# scrapy navigating to next pages listed in the first crawl page

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi i need help with the following code to navigate and obtain the data from the remaining pages in the link mentioned in the start_urls. Please help

```
class texashealthspider(CrawlSpider):

    name="texashealth2"
    allowed_domains=['www.texashealth.org']
    start_urls=['http://jobs.texashealth.org/search/']

    rules=(
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("startrow=\d",)),callback="parse",follow=True),
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles=hxs.select('//tbody/tr/td')
        items = []

    for titles in titles:
        item=TexashealthItem()
        item['title']=titles.select('span[@class="jobTitle"]/a/text()').extract()
        item['link']=titles.select('span[@class="jobTitle"]/a/@href').extract()
        item['shifttype']=titles.select('span[@class="jobShiftType"]/text()').extract()
        item['location']=titles.select('span[@class="jobLocation"]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    print items
    return items
```

Comment: What happens? what's wrong?

Comment: The navigation was not happening through the pages that were in the webpage. Scrapy was crawling only through the start page and did not crawl the rest of the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the restriction in the `allowed_domains=['www.texashealth.org']`, make it `allowed_domains=['texashealth.org']` or `allowed_domains=['jobs.texashealth.org']` - otherwise **no** page will be crawled

btw, consider changing function name, from docs:

> Warning
>
> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer work.

Comment: Hey, the solution you mentioned worked well. But i have one more issue which i will be glad if you helped. The crawling was taking place well in the remaining webpages but the crawl is not taking place in the start-url mentioned. Do you think it has something to do with the way i defined the xpaths? i was getting only 661 records instead of 686 records present in all the pages together.

Comment: try to change `allow=("startrow=\d",)` to `allow=("search/",)` also keep in mind that scrapy will not crawl a page twice, maybe its not skipping first page, check that the links are unique

Comment: Hi, i tried it that way but i am still getting the same result. Any other ideas?